# Remove users from database (Ruby on Rails, Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to create a button to remove users from the database.

In the **routes** I have:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
  match 'users/:id' => 'registrations#destroy', :via => :delete, :as => :admin_destroy_user
```

**registration_controller**:

```
def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.destroy
      redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

**_backoffice.html.erb** file:

```
<%= button_to 'Delete', admin_destroy_user_path(user.id), :class => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm', :method => :delete, data: {:confirm => 'Tem a certeza que quer apagar este utilizador?'} %>
```

**And this is the error I'm getting:**

NoMethodError in RegistrationsController#destroy

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

```
  def resource_name
    devise_mapping.name
  end
  alias :scope_name :resource_name
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please type out the error messages, do not include pictures.

Comment: ok, I'm sorry, working on it right now.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that there is no method named `destroy` in the  `RegistrationsController`. But in your post, you reference this controller as: `registration_controller` (i.e. with no "s")

Perhaps you have defined your RegistrationController as singular, not plural?